# How to group transfers by IP address in C to calculate transfer rates?

Tags: c

I am beginner in C and I'm stuck on an interesting problem.

I am catching all outgoing packets on port 80 and I would like to calculate transfer speed per IP. But the problem is that I have no clue how to group these IP addresses, in PHP I could create an array and index entries by IP and search an array and if IP index already exists update value bytes transferred and then divide it by seconds elapsed and I've got transfer speed in B/s. But in C I can not do this.

Suggest me please how to achieve my problem, because now I can only calculate overall transfer speed.

```
  t2 = time(0);
  time_elapsed = (int) (t2-t1);
  if(time_elapsed > 0) {
    bytes += Size;
    //packets size SUM from all IP addresses, which is incorrect

    printf("IP: %s | Size: %d\n\n", inet_ntoa(dest.sin_addr), Size);
  }
```

Output

```
IP: 77.236.192.100 | Size: 4434

IP: 89.176.81.106 | Size: 43854

IP: 89.176.81.106 | Size: 20494

IP: 89.176.81.106 | Size: 24874

IP: 77.236.192.100 | Size: 7354

IP: 89.176.81.106 | Size: 39474

IP: 89.176.81.106 | Size: 16114
```

Comment: In C++ it would be extremely easy to do with a `std::map`. Does it have to be in C?

Comment: Well I've decided to learn C first, so yes, C please :)

Comment: are you familiar with linked lists? some sort of data structure like that is going to be the easiest if not most performant way to deal with this.

Comment: Not yet. Thanks for pointing me out, will read about linked lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C you can use chained nodes with pointers, also known as queues, lists or stacks (depending on how its structured). I have a code that might just work for you:

```
struct _ip_map_node {
    struct _ip_map_node* next;
    unsigned long ip;
    unsigned long transfered;
    unsigned long time;
};
typedef struct _ip_map_node ip_map_node;

ip_map_node* update_or_create_ip_map_node(ip_map_node** queue, unsigned long ip, unsigned long transfered) {
    ip_map_node* node = *queue;
    while (node) {
        if (node->ip == ip) {
            node->transfered += transfered;
            return node;
        }
        node = node->next;
    }
    node = malloc(sizeof(ip_map_node));
    node->next = *queue;
    *queue = node;

    node->ip = ip;
    node->transfered = transfered;
    node->time = time(NULL);

    return node;
}

void remove_ip_map_node(ip_map_node** queue, unsigned long ip) {
    ip_map_node* last = NULL;
    ip_map_node* curr = *queue;
    while (curr) {
        if (curr->ip == ip) {
            if (last)
                last->next = curr->next;
            else
                *queue = curr->next;

            free(curr);
            break;
        }
        last = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}

ip_map_node* my_ip_map = NULL;
```

I made some changes to best fit your purpose and didn't check if it compile, if you have trouble figuring it out I can assist you.

This is basically how you use it: You have a list of IPs named `my_ip_map`, its empty by default.

You can create elements in it or update it by using:

```
ip_map_node* node = update_or_create_ip_map_node(&my_ip_map, dest.sin_addr.s_addr, data_size);
```

Where `data_size` is the number of bytes being transfered to that IP at that moment. It will automatically sum to the amount that was previously sent to the same IP.

This `node` then has the properties:

```
node->ip; // The IP in numeric format, use inet_ntoa() to transform it
node->transfered; // The amount that was transfered to that IP so far
node->time; // the time(NULL) when the first packet was sent to this IP
```

You now can get the transfer speed using `node->transfered / (time(NULL) - node->time)` -- be careful because a division by zero will crash.

If you want to reset this node every a couple seconds you can use:

```
node->transfered = 0;
node->time = time(NULL);
```

Or remove it with:

```
remove_ip_map_node(&my_ip_map, dest.sin_addr);
```

And to run all IPs in the list you can use for instance:

```
ip_map_node* node = my_ip_map;
while(node) {
    printf("%s, %d\n", inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr *)&node->ip), node->transfered);
    node = node->next;
}
```

For performance reasons, its structured as a stack (elements added last appear first).

Comment: Thanks, this is such a great example! Will try to get the point! Actually I was imagining it to be something like this, but never seen an example. *THUMBS UP*

Comment: `sniffer.c: In function ‘print_tcp_packet’:
sniffer.c:254:5: error: incompatible type for argument 2 of ‘update_or_create_ip_map_node’
sniffer.c:52:14: note: expected ‘long unsigned int’ but argument is of type ‘struct in_addr’
sniffer.c:257:7: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘inet_ntoa’
In file included from sniffer.c:10:0:
/usr/include/arpa/inet.h:54:14: note: expected ‘struct in_addr’ but argument is of type ‘long unsigned int’` I have no idea to which format to convert it :/

Comment: Passed an argument `dest.sin_addr.s_addr` and it solved 1/2 of the errors, but still fails in `while() inet_ntoa(node->ip)`

Comment: Oh, its because `inet_ntoa()` takes a `struct in_addr` as argument, use `inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr *)&node->ip)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In **C++**, if you need a associative container, which you can access by a string containing the IP, you can use the [map container](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/), of type `map< string, float >` (of course if you store the IP's using strings)

Then you can access the elements just by doing `yourMapName[IPaddress]`.

If you need to do it in **C**, you need to do a `struct` containing the IP address (if it's pure C, you'll probably use `char*`, and an `unsigned int`. Then you'll need to do an array of those structures and a function which searches the array for a structure with a given `char*` and adds to the int, or adds a new entry in the array.

If you need to make the structure array flexible (because you don't know how many IP's will be connecting), you'll need to learn how to use the `malloc` and `free` C functions.

So if you're not stuck with pure C - it's way more straightforward to do it in C++. Just a hint, it's your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Don't implement this yourself, use one of the vast amount of libraries available for C. An example with glib:

```
#include <glib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned lookup(GHashTable *dict, const char *key)
{
    return GPOINTER_TO_UINT(g_hash_table_lookup(dict, key));
}

void accumulate(GHashTable *dict, char *key, unsigned increment)
{
    unsigned value;

    value = lookup(dict, key);
    g_hash_table_insert(dict, key, GUINT_TO_POINTER(value + increment));
}

int main(void)
{
    GHashTable *ip;

    ip = g_hash_table_new(g_str_hash, g_str_equal);
    accumulate(ip, "10.1.1.1", 0);
    accumulate(ip, "10.10.10.10", 2);
    accumulate(ip, "10.1.1.1", 2);
    accumulate(ip, "10.1.1.1", 3);
    accumulate(ip, "10.2.2.2", 10);

    printf("%u\n", lookup(ip, "10.1.1.1"));
    printf("%u\n", lookup(ip, "10.10.10.10"));
    printf("%u\n", lookup(ip, "10.2.2.2"));

    g_hash_table_unref(ip);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./hash 
5
2
10
```

https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.38/glib-Hash-Tables.html